# MemberOf in Graph Me api azure AD

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, auth0, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to get the member groups of the user to whom user belongs using azure graph api but it is not returning memberof in the api. I am using auth0 for the authentication.

Here is the java script code which I am using.

```
function(accessToken, ctx, cb) {
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken@7.1.9');
console.log('azure - retrieve user profile');
// Retrieve the profile from Azure
request.get(
'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=id,mail,givenName,surname,userPrincipalName,otherMails,department,memberOf', {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
  },
  json: true
},
function(e, r, profile) {
  if (e) {
    console.log('azure - error while retrieving user profile:');
    console.log(e);
    return cb(e)
  }
  if (r.statusCode !== 200) {
    console.log('azure - error while retrieving user profile: ' + r.statusCode);
    return cb(new Error('StatusCode: ' + r.statusCode));
  }
  console.log('azure - retrieved user profile.');
  // Get the tenant id from the access token
  let decodedToken = jwt.decode(accessToken);
  let auth0Profile = {
    user_id: profile.id,
    given_name: profile.givenName,
    family_name: profile.surname,
    email: profile.mail || profile.otherMails[0] || profile.userPrincipalName,
    email_verified: true,
    name: profile.givenName + ' ' + profile.surname,
    tenant_id: decodedToken.tid,
    identification_value: decodedToken.tid,
    user_principal_name: profile.userPrincipalName,
    user_department: profile.department,
    user_member: profile.memberOf
   };
  cb(null, auth0Profile);
  }
  );
  }
```

I have added scope (User.Read Directory.Read.All) in Auth0 for the api call.
Can some one let me know why I am not getting memberOf?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get **member groups** of the user, along with multiple **attributes**, the query will not return the expected results.

I tried checking the same query in **Microsoft Graph Explorer**.

```
'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=id,mail,givenName,surname,userPrincipalName,otherMails,department,memberOf'
```

Even
for that, except **memberOf**, all objects displayed:

[image]

For getting **memberOf**, you have to query separately like below:

**`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf`**

[image]

So, for the **workaround**, you can make use of the above query by giving it separately without querying with other attributes.

Also please make sure to add **GroupMember.Read.All** permissions in the scope as mentioned in this [**Microsoft Doc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).

Please find below links if they are helpful: [**Ref1**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#limited-information-returned-for-inaccessible-member-objects), [**Ref2**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request)